# Auto complete / prefix matching like google:: Trie/Dwag/sphinx/lucene

Tags: lucene, sphinx, trie

Hi have heard Trie is best for auto suggester/auto complete.
But dwag uses less space so I guess dwag should be better.

Also if Sphinx/Lucene can do prefix matching so why shouldn't we use it.

Also Trie/dwag is good for small tables ??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What is dwag? More importantly, what problem are you trying to solve? Reading your question is like jumping in on the middle of a conversation. You might get help here if you provide more context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see with [DAWGs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_word_graph); DAWGs are relatively complex. You can get a unique path through all words (in order to associate some data with the key, which you usually want), but it's a lot harder than using a trie which is only prefix-compressed and will have unique terminal nodes. The suffix compression you get by using a DAWG is only worth it if you're *very* memory limited (like on an embedded device), which you probably aren't since you mention Lucene.

A prefix tree is designed for this task. It's perfect. If you need to write your own, that's where you'd go. Of course, there are also many libraries available for this already, perfectly suitable if you don't have special needs.